# C#:Visual-Studio: How to maximize a specific panel on a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 panels on a winform. How can I maximize `Panel2` when I maximize the winform?

I have tried anchoring `Panel1` to Top and Left, and anchoring `Panel2` to all margins (Top, Bottom, Left and Right).

But this way, `Panel1` remains fixed but `Panel2` didn't resize when the winform is maximized!

Is there any way to fix this problem or is it possible to maximize `Panel2` alone with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add panel1 docked to the top then add panel2 with dock type set to "fill"

Comment: This will dock panel1 at the top, and panel2 at the bottom, but both will fill the left to right space. panel 2 will fill all the bottom space.